# Using Huggingface zero-shot text classification with large data set

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use Huggingface zero-shot text classification using 12 labels with large data set (57K sentences) read from a CSV file as follows:

```
csv_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('batch.csv', filename)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
classifier = pipeline('zero-shot-classification')
results = classifier(df['description'].to_list(), labels, multi_class=True)
```

This keeps crashing as python runs out of memory.
I tried to create a dataset instead as follows:

```
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files=filename)
```

But not sure how to use it with Huggingface's classifier. What is the best way to batch process classification?

I eventually would like to feed it over 1M sentences for classification.

Comment: Try using tf.Data: it helps you to read big dataset and does not make the program OOM: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data

Comment: Thank but can I feed it into the huggingface classifier?

Comment: If your model uses TF version I think it might work

Comment: The ZeroShotClassificationPipeline expects a list of sentences so this is not possible using the current implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that your dataset is too big to fit into RAM, but that you're trying to pass the whole thing through a large transformer model at once. Hugging Face's pipelines don't do any mini-batching under the hood at the moment, so pass the sequences one by one or in small subgroups instead:

```py
results = [classifier(desc, labels, multi_class=True for desc in df['description']]
```

If you're using a GPU, you'll get the best speed by using as many sequences at each pass as will fit into the GPU's memory, so you could try the following:

```py
batch_size = 4 # see how big you can make this number before OOM
classifier = pipeline('zero-shot-classification', device=0) # to utilize GPU
sequences = df['description'].to_list()
results = []
for i in range(0, len(sequences), batch_size):
    results += classifier(sequences[i:i+batch_size], labels, multi_class=True)
```

and see how large you can make `batch_size` before you get OOM errors.

Comment: hi Joe: I'm trying to use the Zero Shot classifier on Databricks and have spun up a GPU enabled cluster to process around 20K small sentences. However, it doesn't seem to be using the GPU - only the CPUs and therefore it's running painfully slow. I even tried adding the "device=0" to the code, but it doesn't have an effect. Do you have any ideas on how to engage the GPU on a Databricks cluster so that it goes faster?

Comment: @SiddarthRanganathan Sorry, no idea. First step of debugging would be to check whether other models in Transformers run on GPU. If that doesn't lead you anywhere, I'd open up an issue in the Transformers repo.

Answer (score 0):

The Zero-shot-classification model takes 1 input in one go, plus it's very heavy model to run, So as recommended run it on GPU only,

The very simple approach is to convert the text into list

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
classifier = pipeline('zero-shot-classification')
filter_keys = ['labels']
output = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  d = {}
  sequence = row['description']
  result = classifier(sequence, labels, multi_class=True)
  temp = list(map(result.get, filter_keys))
  d['description'] = row['description']
  d['label'] = temp[0][0]
  output.append(d) 

 #convert the list of dictionary into pandas DataFrame
 new = pd.DataFrame(output)
 new.head()
```